# An improper integral from PUTNAM preparatory problems

Tags: definite-integrals, contest-math, improper-integrals

Evaluate the improper integral  $\int^1_0 ln(x)\cdot ln(1-x)dx$.
I got it from this link:[https://www.math.ust.hk/~yangwang/Misc/putnam_first100.pdf](https://www.math.ust.hk/%7Eyangwang/Misc/putnam_first100.pdf)

Kindly give me a hint to solve it.

Comment: WolframAlpha knows how to solve it: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+ln%28x%29ln%281-x%29dx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\ln(1-x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}x^n$$

$$\int_0^1\ln(x)x^ndx =-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} =\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$